# How to remove duplicate domains from a URL list using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am stuck at a rather simple problem - removing duplicate domains from a list of URL's, using javascript.

Here's what I am currently doing:
I have an array called 'list' which has the list of url's. I work on that to extract the domains, and put them in a new array called 'domain'.

Then I use two for loops to go through the entire list and check for duplicate domains. If the domains match, I splice the duplicate one out. But it seems to be removing too many, and I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong, or suggest a simpler/better way of doing it?

```
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {

    for (j=i+1; j<list.length; j++) {

        if (domain[i] == domain[j]) {

            console.log('REMOVING:');
            console.log(i + '. ' + list2[i]);
            console.log(j + '. ' + list2[j]);
            console.log(domain[i]);
            console.log(domain[j]);

            list.splice(j,1);

        }
    }
}
```

This is not a 'how to remove duplicates from an array' question. As I have a list of URL's, and need to check for - and remove, only the duplicate 'domains'. So suppose I have 4 URL's from youtube, I need to keep only the first one and remove the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: hi koffeinfrei, my question is a little different - as I have two arrays - one with the url list and one with the domains. I need to check for duplicates from the domain list, and remove them from the url's list.

Comment: And never change list, which you iterate))

Comment: I think I found the error - I was splicing only one of the arrays and not both of them. Was only splicing the URL array, and not the domain array. But I would like to leave the question open in case somebody has a more 'elegant' solution for this problem - removing duplicate domains from a list of URL's (using JS)

Answer (score 3):

ES5: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array and only include if the current item's index is equal to its index in the array:

```
list.filter(function(elem, pos, arr) {
   return arr.indexOf(elem) === pos;
});
```

ES6: use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
const uniqueDomains = [ ...new Set(list) ];
```

or if you can't use the spread operator:

```
new Set(list).toJSON()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to get rid of the domains array. Instead build a map of already "used" domains:

```
var urls = [
  'http://example.org/page-1.html',
  'http://example.org/page-2.html',
  'http://google.com/search.html',
  'http://mozilla.com/foo.html',
];

var domains = {};
var uniqueUrls = urls.filter(function(url) {
  // whatever function you're using to parse URLs
  var domain = extractDomain(url);
  if (domains[domain]) {
    // we have seen this domain before, so ignore the URL
    return false;
  }
  // mark domain, retain URL
  domains[domain] = true;
  return true;
});

console.log(uniqueUrls);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let an object handle the checking for you.

```
var a = [];

a.push('http://test')
a.push('http://that');
a.push('http://that');
a.push('http://that');

var o = {}

for(var ii = 0; ii < a.length; ii++){
    o[a[ii]] = o[a[ii]]
}

var nA = [];

for (var k in o) {
    nA.push(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the Undescore.js library, it's as simple as

```
yourArray = _.uniq(yourArray);
```

http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove duplicates is to use a map. The example has an array of URIs with some duplicates. First insert the strings into an object, then iterate over the object to create an array. Boom, no duplicates.

```js
function getHostName(url) {
    var match = url.match(/:\/\/(www[0-9]?\.)?(.[^/:]+)/i);
    if (match != null && match.length > 2 && typeof match[2] === 'string' && match[2].length > 0) {
    return match[2];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

var uris = ["http://foo.org/barbar","http://www.bar.com/foo/bar/bar.html","http://foo.bar/lorem/","http://foo.org","https://bar.bar","http://foo.org","http://bar.bar"];
var urisObj = {};
for(var i = 0;i<uris.length;i++){
  urisObj[getHostName(uris[i])] = getHostName(uris[i]);
}

uris = Object.keys(urisObj).map(function(x) { return urisObj[x];});

console.log(uris);
```

**Edit:**

Using http://www.primaryobjects.com/2012/11/19/parsing-hostname-and-domain-from-a-url-with-javascript/ to get the host name from a string.

Comment: The URL's in my list don't just include the domains, but pages too.. Like foo.com/page1.html, bar.com/whatever/p1.html. I need to check for duplicates in domains alone. [Right now I have two arrays, one with full URLs and one with domains alone]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using your original way (or very similar to it), instead of going up the array (with `i++`) - go down the array instead. As in the following code,

```
var list = ["abc", "cba", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"];

for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  for (var j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {

    if (list[i] == list[j]) {

        console.log('REMOVING:');
        console.log(i + '. ' + list[i]);
        console.log(j + '. ' + list[j]);
        console.log(list[i]);
        console.log(list[j]);

        list.splice(i, 1);

    }
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

Comment: In general, removing elements from an array and going up at the same time is a horrible idea. Think about it. :)